# Paypal REST API - Is Access Token Reusable?

Tags: php, rest, paypal

According to [paypal rest docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/), for every transaction to paypal I need to submit an 'Authorization:Bearer' which is an access token that is generated from a previous request. I wasn't able to glean from the docs whether or not the 'access_token' can be re-used for multiple requests over it's lifetime? My thought here is to cache the response (on my end) for 6 hours, so I can limit the number of requests to paypal, which should be fine, because the expiry from paypal is 8 hours.

Anyone know if I can re-use the generated access_token for multiple, exclusive transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the access token can be reused over multiple requests for the lifetime of the token.

In fact, I would recommend it; like you said it cuts down on the number of requests you need to make to us.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks for the response. I'd recommend adding that to the dev docs, it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for an answer to this as well. It is obvious that this token should be reusable but I failed to find out how and its duration. 
Finally, I found a valid resource at the last paragraph [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/) , stating that it is reusable, for the duration provided as the response header (or variable? (NVP)) "expires_in".

But note that nowadays the SDK has the capability to do this for you. Say no more and head straight to [this page](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Caching) for more information.